# Autolayout constraints work in iOS 8 and break in iOS 9

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, ios9

I have a Xcode 6.2 project written in Swift. The problem is that I the auto layout constraints that work fine on iOS 8 break on iOS 9 Beta 5 (worked in Beta 1 not sure about the others). I've redone the constraints and researched the problem, but I can't find any way to fix this problem on iOS 9. Is there any reason this might be happening?

I can upload anything you need to help find a solution; I didn't upload the constraints because it seems to be an app wide problem not specific to any constraints.

Comment: Upload a screen shot of one of the problems, including the error in console.

Comment: There is no error in the console. It's only the UI that messes up

Comment: 'beak' is not a very descriptive error. Post the full error or screenshot of the problem and post sample code reproducing the issue.

Comment: "I didn't upload the constraints because it seems to be an app wide problem not specific to any constraints." Well it's not an app wide problem for anyone else, so maybe you'd better provide some specifics, eh? Constraints did not magically break in iOS 9 beta 5. _You_ must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Could that be because you are using a different simulator with a different screen size?

Comment: I have the same problem. My table view cells are rendered differently in iOS 9 than in iOS 8. Same app, same phone but different rendering. In iOS 9 the table view cell contents no longer fit. It's just as if the screen became a couple of pixels less wide.

Comment: I have the same problem also. In my App on iOS9 in TableView are most of all constraints brocken. "Update constraints" is not working :-( Hier is the picture in iOS9 now: one dynamic cell is ok, and another is upset. How is it possible??

Hier is the example picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c7caZ.png

Answer (score 0):

@jamespick You have to update your container view not whole `UIViewController`.

Let me explain with some line of code.
Before IOS 9...

```
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

After and all version later IOS 9...

```
[self.containerView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.containerView setNeedsLayout];
```

Because IOS 9 and later version you can no longer call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `setNeedsLayout` on a view and expect the constraints of subviews to update.